# Запрос в SQLite один-к-многим через RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, recyclerview

Приветствую! Недавно я не мог разобрать, как происходит запрос один-к-многим, но получил ответ и понял как это работает, однако, при реализации приложения у меня возникла проблема на данном этапе, а именно, я не могу составить правильный запрос "один-к-многим". У меня есть БД с двумя таблицами где:

Таблица 1 `Head_Table` где 100 глав.

```
| id | HEAD    |
----------------
| 1  | Глава 1 |
| 2  | Глава 2 |
```

Таблица 2 `Content_Table` где содержимое более 300

```
| id |   CONTENT    | KEY |
---------------------------
| 1  | Содержимое 1 |  1  |
| 2  | Содержимое 2 |  1  |
| 3  | Содержимое 3 |  2  |
| 4  | Содержимое 4 |  3  |
| 5  | Содержимое 5 |  3  |
```

Далее, в `MainActivity` я получаю первую таблицу и распределяю ее размер на фрагменты:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        int section_number = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        DBAssetHelper dbSetup = new DBAssetHelper(getActivity());
        dbSetup.getReadableDatabase();

        try{
            SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DBSQLiteOpenHelper(getActivity());
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(
                    "HEAD_TABLE", new String[]{"HEAD"},
                    "_id = ?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(section_number)},
                    null, null, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                String HEAD = cursor.getString(0);

                TextView head_content = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.head_content);

                head_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(HEAD));

            }

            cursor.close();
            db.close();

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Где `section_number` это длина возвращаемых через `PlaceholderFragment` фрагментов, что соответствует длине `Head` в первой таблице. Таким образом во всех 100 фрагментах я вывожу название 100 глав из таблицы `Head_Table`.

Затем в используемый макет под `TextView` который отображает название глав я помещаю `RecyclerView`:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/head_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_contents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

В котором я хочу отобразить содержимое второй таблицы по примеру один-к-многим.
Для этого я создал класс `Contents`:

```
class Contents {

private String content_one;

Contents(String content_one) {
    this.content_one = content_one;
}

String getContent_one() {
    return content_one;
}}
```

Адаптер `TheContentsAdapter`:

```
class TheContentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TheContentsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Contents> mContent;

TheContentsAdapter(List<Contents> contentItem) {
    this.mContent = contentItem;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.content_item, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.mContent_one.setText(mContent.get(position).getContent_one());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mContent.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView mContent_one;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mContent_one = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.c_one);
    }
}}
```

А также класс `DBSQLiteOpenHelper` где я открываю БД и создаю `ArrayList` для `TheContentsAdapter:`

```
class DBSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DBVersion = 1;
private static final String DBName = "BookDB";
private static final String TableName = "CONTENT_TABLE";
private static final String mId = "_id";
private static final String mContent= "CONTENT";
private static final String mKey = "KEY";

private static final String[] myColumns = {mId, mContent, mKey};

private static final String mTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TableName +
        "(" + "_id" + mContent + " TEXT, " + mKey + " TEXT)";

DBSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(mTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableName);
    this.onCreate(db);
}

List<Contents> getHeadsItem(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.query(TableName, // a. table
            myColumns, // b. column names
            null, // c. selections
            null, // d. selections args
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null); // h. limit

    List<Contents> headsItem = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            headsItem.add(new Contents(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mContent)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mKey))));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return headsItem;
}}
```

И в `MainActivity` после реализации `Head_Table` я связываю `Content_Table` и адаптер и передаю содержимое в `RecyclerView`:

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_contents);

DBSQLiteOpenHelper db = new DBSQLiteOpenHelper(getActivity());
List<Contents> namesItem = db.getHeadsItem();

LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),
LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TheContentsAdapter(namesItem));
```

Итог: У меня 100 прокручиваемых глав, и `TextView` который отображает название каждой главы. Но `RecyclerView` в каждой главе выкладывает всю длину `Content_Table`, так как в `TheContentsAdapter` указано:

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mContent.size();
}
```

Я не могу понять, как именно мне нужно заставить `KEY` из таблицы `Content_Table` ссылаться на `_id` из таблицы `Head_Table` чтобы в каждой главе `RecyclerView` выдавал `KEY` соответствующий `_id` таблицы `Head_Table`?

Comment: Очень много лишней информации, в которой тяжело разобраться. Конкретный вопрос в том, что вы не знаете как из `Content_Table` достать только те записи, которые относятся к нужной главе из `Head_Table`?

Comment: Да, именно так!

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы `RecyclerView` на текущей странице, где `_id` таблицы `Head_Table` например 1, отображал из `Content_Table` всё содержимое где `KEY` равен 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить в запрос параметры selections и selection_args. Метод для получения контента по id главы:

```
List<Contents> getHeadsItem(long headId) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.query(TableName, // a. table
            myColumns, // b. column names
            "KEY=?", // c. selections
            new String[]{String.valueOf(headId)}, // d. selections args
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null); // h. limit

    List<Contents> headsItem = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            headsItem.add(new Contents(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mContent)),
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mKey))));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return headsItem;
}
```

Подробнее о параметрах в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Не понятно с `long id`, после того как добавил, строка `List<Contents> namesItem = db.getHeadsItem();` в `MainActivity` ругается. Скобки после `getHeadsItem` подчеркнуты красным, что туда нужно добавить?

Comment: Значение `KEY` для которого нужен контент. Например 1, как вы писали в комменте.

Comment: В моем случае это `section_number` который определяет длину глав, я добавил его, но содержимое `content_table` распределилось на каждую страницу 1. То есть, вместо того, чтобы там, где `_id`  = 1 отобразить `key` = 1 два раза, `KEY` просто распределился по своему `_id` 1 к 1

Comment: Я снова вас не понимаю. Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос понятней. Или добавьте в вопрос картинки, что вы хотите получить и что у вас получилось сейчас.

Comment: Я добавил в эти скобки и значение `KEY` из `Content_Table` и значение `_id` из `Head_Table` по очереди, в первом случае вообще пусто, во втором случае, в макете отобразилось одно содержимое из `Content_Table` вместо двух. и таким образом в каждой главе по одному содержимому вместо разного количества.

Comment: `_id` должен быть разный для каждой главы. У вас так?

Comment: Да, но `_id` из `Head_Table` ссылается на `_id` из `Content_Table` а мне нужно чтобы он ссылался на `key` в этом собственно и вся проблема.

Comment: @McDaggen Поправил код в ответе. Нужно `KEY=?` вместо `_id=?`. И в метод нужно передавать id главы, то есть `_id` из `Head_Table`.

Comment: Вот теперь работает!

Answer (score 1):

@McDaggen вдогонку к уже решенной проблеме.

Настоятельно рекомендую использовать адаптер [RecyclerViewCursorAdapter](https://github.com/androidessence/RecyclerViewCursorAdapter), который реализует адаптер к `RecyclerView` берущий данные из `Cursor`

В этом случае у вас и код будет чище/проще (не надо будет в каждом вызове `onCreateView` городить запрос к БД. Надо будет просто создать к обоим `RecyclerView` по разным `Cursor`ам и во втором `RecyclerView` позиционироваться в курсоре через `id` переданный от первого списка.

И еще одно замечание в Android первичный ключ требуется называть `_ID`, иначе с курсорами может случиться беда.

Comment: при создании БД вместо `_id` называть `_ID`? Или имя переменной вместо `mId` `_ID`?

Comment: И раз уж вы обратили внимание, подскажите, насколько целесообразно новичку использовать сторонние библиотеки?

Comment: Смысл ООП и вообще программирования состоит в том, чтобы не писать все самому, а использовать сторонние наработки. С чисто прогерской точки зрения использование сторонней библиотеки технически ничем не сложнее использования методов API SDK

Comment: все же имя колонки первичного ключа в БД должно быть  [именно _id](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_ID), а не _ID (или константа системы `BaseColumns._ID`).

Comment: @pavlofff принимается :)